# Custom Keyboard Throwing Exceptions

Tags: java, android, exception

I have a simple enough idea, which is to make a custom keyboard instead of using the built in keyboard to avoid autocorrect, symbols, numbers, etc. which I don't want in my app. For some reason, when I call the event typeKey to "type" a letter, the event calling itself throws an exception.

Here is the java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Vector<String> answer = new Vector<String>(1,1);
    int ansLength = 1;
    private TextView answerbox;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        answerbox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerbox);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public void typeKey(Object sender)
    {
        Button pressed = (Button) sender;
        answer.add(ansLength, (String) pressed.getText());
        ansLength++;
        answerbox.setText((CharSequence) answer);
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant XML:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/q"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Q"
            android:onClick="typeKey"/>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/answerbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="43dp"
        android:layout_y="40dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

The goal is to be able to type and have the typed text show up as the textview. My thought to do this was to add to every key an event, typeKey, which would get the text from whatever button called the event, add it to the vector "answer", and then set the textview to display the text of "answer".

Here is the whole stack trace:

```
08-06 13:04:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(15224): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 13:04:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(15224): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-06 13:04:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(15224):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3698)
08-06 13:04:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(15224):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
08-06 13:04:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(15224):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17273)
08-06 13:04:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(15224):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-06 13:04:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(15224):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-06 13:04:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(15224):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-06 13:04:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(15224):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
08-06 13:04:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(15224):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 13:04:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(15224):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-06 13:04:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(15224):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
08-06 13:04:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(15224):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
08-06 13:04:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(15224):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 13:04:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(15224): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-06 13:04:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(15224):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 13:04:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(15224):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-06 13:04:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(15224):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3693)
08-06 13:04:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(15224):    ... 11 more
08-06 13:04:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(15224): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Vector cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
08-06 13:04:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(15224):    at gguday.lexiconicmkii.MainActivity.typeKey(MainActivity.java:42)
08-06 13:04:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(15224):    ... 14 more
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please add stackTrace

Comment: @Elist I'm sorry, I'm not sure actually what that is... I'm new to this, this is my first app outside of a prebuilt wrapper. Do you mean the LogCat?

Comment: You say you got an exception, but never said what kind of exception or where it was thrown from. A `stack trace` gives exactly these two pieces of information: a) a list (stack) of methods called since the beginning of the Thread (say, the beginning of your program) to the method where the exception was "thrown" (i.e. created) AND b) the kind of exception thrown (it's `class`) and a custom message. Where to find the trace depends on your IDE (are you working with eclipse? AndriodStudio?) but if you know you got an exception it means you saw it somewhere, so you should be able to find it.

Comment: @Elist I'm working with Eclipse, but can't seem to find the stack trace. However to answer what excpetions were thrown, upon the press of the button (I set a breakpoint at the method declaration) just before it reaches the method it already opens up "Class File Editor: Source not found" page, and upon the step through I get an Invocation Target Exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three issues:

You are trying to search for your `answerbox` view before you call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`. This will always result in `answerbox` being null since there are no views available (yet) and throw a `NullPointerException` when you try to access `answerbox`. Make sure to switch the order and search for `answerbox` after you call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

Ex.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
answerbox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerbox);
```

Second, change your click method to take a `View` as the parameter (instead of `Object`) as onClick methods expect this.. Although, I think what you have should be ok since a View technically is an object and you are casting it to the appropriate type. I'm not sure how picky it is when trying to call the click listener so for safety I'd just change it to `View`. 
 Ex.

```
public void typeKey(View sender)
{
        Button pressed = (Button) sender;
        answer.add(ansLength, (String) pressed.getText());
        ansLength++;
        answerbox.setText((CharSequence) answer);
}
```

Lastly,

You cannot simply cast your vector to a CharSequence. If you wish to make a string out of it you will have to loop through each value and add it to a larger string.. Ex.

```
public void typeKey(View sender)
{
    Button pressed = (Button) sender;
    answer.add(ansLength, (String) pressed.getText());
    ansLength++;


    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String string : answer) {
        stringBuilder.append(string);
    }

    answerbox.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
}
```

You should also start your ansLength at 0 since the vectors are zero indexed.

```
int ansLength = 1;
```

Comment: I changed my code to avoid the errors you pointed out, however after saving and then rerunning, I still get the same errors followed by a crash. Specifically a Class File Editor: Source Not Found for the Vector class, and upon the execution of the method an Invocation Target Exception.

Comment: @GilGuday I made an edit to include why that is (hopefully) crashing. If not try looking at logcat and grabbing the entire stacktrace. Logcat is found in the DDMS view of eclipse. There is a Logcat tab in there.

Comment: @ dymmeh I tried setting the ansLength to 0 as well, still doesn't run. BTW, I thought that with vectors specifically the 0 entry is null? Was I wrong?

Comment: I see the logcat and all the errors it registered, but how do I "get the stack trace"?

Comment: @GilGuday - you can just highlight all of the rows for the error and copy them using ctrl+C (assuming you're on windows). A simple way would be to set the Logcat filter to error.. Click the clear log button. And then run your app so it crashes. Then copy the red text that shows up. Clearing the log beforehand will make it so only the error from your app will be showing

Comment: @GilGuday - A Vector is basically a List that uses all synchronized method calls. So, position 0 will have a value.

Comment: I got something around 30 errors, too much to even post in a comment. They are all runtime errors, seeming to center mostly around handler and java.lang exceptions

Comment: @GilGuday - I see you updated your question with the stacktraces. I updated my answer as well.

Comment: thanks so much, that code bit worked! So just for my knowledge in the future, why didn't that line work before and why does it work now?

Comment: When casting you're trying to change one datatype (vector) to another datatype (charsequence). Since a vector is not a Charsequence nor a subtype of charsequence, there is no way to cast it and that's why you get the class cast exceptions. With the new code we are looking at each individual item in the Vector which is a String. Since that's already in a format we can add to a TextView we simply use a StringBuilder to form a larger String and then set the contents of the TextView to be that StringBuilder. I hope that helps a bit.